# Negative id value in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In the main activity I create database

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {

               super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                  + "id integer primary key autoincrement," 
                  + "name text," 
                  + "obId text," 
                  + "latit text,"
                  + "long text" + ");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
      }
```

In the second activity I call the class of database

```
MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
dbHelper = myActivity.new DBHelper(myActivity);
```

And insert data

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
db = openOrCreateDatabase("myDB.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
cv.put("name", textViewName.getText().toString());
long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
dbHelper.close();
```

The output "rowID" is "-1". I do not understand why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getWritableDatabase()` on your database helper instead of `openOrCreateDatabase()` on a `Context` to get a database reference. You're operating on two different databases, out of which the other doesn't have the table you're attempting to insert to.

Also, you're inserting the same data twice.

> If I use db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); I will in Log java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.ja‌​va:118) at com.ex.test.AddPoint.writePointsToDatabase(Add.java:264) at com.ex.test.AddPoint$3$2.onClick(Add.java:238)

That's because of you've passed in an invalid `Context` to the helper here:

```
MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
dbHelper = myActivity.new DBHelper(myActivity);
```

You cannot instantiate activities with `new`. In an activity, use `this` to refer to a valid `Context`.

Comment: If I use `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` I will in Log   `java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
at com.ex.test.AddPoint.writePointsToDatabase(Add.java:264)
at com.ex.test.AddPoint$3$2.onClick(Add.java:238)`

Comment: 264 line is `db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase ();`

Comment: That's because you've supplied an invalid `Context` to sqlite helper constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> You're operating on two different databases

That is "myDB" in

```
           super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
```

as opposed to "myDB.db" in

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("myDB.db", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
```

Best